# Read complete penn treebank dataset from local directory

Tags: python, nltk, penn-treebank

I have a complete penn treebank dataset and I want to read it using `ptb` from `ntlk.corpus`. But in [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#parsed-corpora) it is said that:

> If you have access to a full installation of the Penn Treebank, NLTK
>   can be configured to load it as well. Download the ptb package, and in
>   the directory nltk_data/corpora/ptb place the BROWN and WSJ
>   directories of the Treebank installation (symlinks work as well). Then
>   use the ptb module instead of treebank:

But i want to keep the dataset in a local directory and then load it from there instead of from `nltk_data/corpora/ptb`. `ptb` always searches in that directory but how can i give a path to `ptb` so that it searches in the given directory? Is there any way i can do that? I have thoroughly searched in web and tried few ways but no way worked for me!

Comment: Use a symlink, like the docs are telling you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your corpus files on your local directory and just add symlinks from an `nltk_data/corpora` folder to the location of your corpus, as the paragraph you quoted suggests. But if you can't modify `nltk_data` or just don't like the idea of a needless round trip through the `nltk_data` directory, read on.

The object `ptb` is just a shortcut to a corpus reader object initialized with the appropriate settings for the Penn Treebank corpus. It is defined (in `nltk/corpus/__init__.py`) like this:

```
ptb = LazyCorpusLoader( # Penn Treebank v3: WSJ and Brown portions
    'ptb', CategorizedBracketParseCorpusReader, r'(WSJ/\d\d/WSJ_\d\d|BROWN/C[A-Z]/C[A-Z])\d\d.MRG',
    cat_file='allcats.txt', tagset='wsj')
```

You can ignore the `LazyCorpusLoader` part; it's used because the nltk defines a lot of corpus endpoints, most of which are never loaded in any one python program. Instead, create a corpus reader by instantiating `CategorizedBracketParseCorpusReader` directly. If your corpus looks exactly like the `ptb` corpus, you'd call it like this:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedBracketParseCorpusReader
myreader = CategorizedBracketParseCorpusReader(r"<path to your corpus>", 
    r'(WSJ/\d\d/WSJ_\d\d|BROWN/C[A-Z]/C[A-Z])\d\d.MRG', 
    cat_file='allcats.txt', tagset='wsj')
```

As you can see, you supply the path to the real location of your files and leave the remaining arguments the same: They are a regexp of file names to include in the corpus, a file mapping corpus files to categories, and the tagset to use. The object you create will be exactly the same corpus reader as `ptb` or `treebank` (except that it is not lazily created).